# JPA "optimistic locking error" - missing record

Tags: java, jpa

I am using "Multiple Table Inheritance" - Child extends Parent (InheritanceType.JOINED)

In case when the Child record is missing, I get "optimistic locking error", when I call remove/commit on the Parent.

What am I missing?

Many thanks.

**Update:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="SEGMENTHEADER")
@Table(name = "EDI_SEGMENT")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Edisegment.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Edisegment d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Edisegment.findByPK", query = "SELECT d FROM Edisegment d WHERE d.seqedi_segment = :seqedi_segment"),
})

public abstract class Edisegment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7304821729574288048L;

    public abstract String toEdiString();

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator...
    @Column(name = "SEQEDI_SEGMENT")
    protected BigDecimal seqedi_segment;
    public BigDecimal getSeqedi_segment(){return seqedi_segment;}
    public void setSeqedi_segment(BigDecimal seqedi_segment ){  this.seqedi_segment = seqedi_segment;}

    public Edisegment(){}
    public Edisegment(BigDecimal seqedi_segment){this.seqedi_segment = seqedi_segment;  }

@Override //toString, equals, hashCode
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("AK1")
@Table(name = "EDIS_AK1")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Edisak1.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Edisak1 d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Edisak1.findByPK", query = "SELECT d FROM Edisak1 d WHERE d.seqedi_segment = :seqedi_segment"),
})
public class Edisak1 extends Edisegment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1787262532664245623L;

    // ======================================
    // =             Attributes             =
    // ======================================
    @Column(name = "FUNCTIONID")
    private String functionid;
    @Column(name = "GROUPCONTROL")
    private BigDecimal groupcontrol;
    @Column(name = "APPREFORIGINATOR")
    private String appreforiginator;

    // ======================================
    // =            c'tor Methods           =
    // ======================================
    public Edisak1(){    }
    public Edisak1(BigDecimal seqedi_segment){    this.seqedi_segment = seqedi_segment;    }

    // ======================================
    // =             getters/setters        =
    // ======================================

    @Override //toString, equals, hashCode
}
```

Comment: you're missing posting some code to demonstrate what you mean.